# 403 - ERR_BAD_REQUEST: Request failed with status code 403 when Lambda invokes ApiGateway Endpoint

Tags: node.js, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am trying to call RestApi on Apigateway from the Lambda function from our VPC(not default, default is working). it throws a 403 error, I couldn't find any details on the CloudWatch logs or Apigateway logs. I think that I am not able to hit Apigateway from Lambda. I tried with Apigateway Resource Policy to allow my VPC request, but nothing changed.

I tried the following things:

- Endpoint is working from Postman and over cURL
- there is no ApiKey
- there is no authX, token, bearer
- I am able to call any external endpoint
- I am able to call Apigateway Endpoint from default VPC

- We are using Nat Instance instead of NatGateway
- problem: Requests from Lambda to Apigateway Endpoint(get, post)

**Lambda/Node.js Code piece:**

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios')

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    'https://XXXX.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/ABC/hello-world/healthcheck',
     {"headers": { "x-api-key": "18yXXXXXXXXXaSI0usGYYYYYY" }})
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res,null,2))
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  }

  return response
}
```

**Error Response**

```
    {
   "message":"Request failed with status code 403",
   "name":"AxiosError",
   "config":{
      "transitional":{
         "silentJSONParsing":true,
         "forcedJSONParsing":true,
         "clarifyTimeoutError":false
      },
      "transformRequest":[
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[
         null
      ],
      "timeout":0,
      "xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength":-1,
      "maxBodyLength":-1,
      "env":{
         
      },
      "headers":{
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
         "x-api-key":"18yXXXXXXXXXaSI0usGYYYYYY",
         "User-Agent":"axios/0.27.2"
      },
      "method":"get",
      "url":"https://XXXX.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/ABC/hello-world/healthcheck"
   },
   "code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
   "status":403
}
```

Comment: Did you use S3 for your project?

Comment: no, it is pure hello world example.